Get <script> tag content with Scrapy
I'm new to Scrapy and am practising fetching pages with it.
My intent is to fetch the content of certain <script> tags, but Scrapy presents a weird behaviour.
Here is a case run from the Scrapy shell.
>>> fetch('https://www.google.com/')
2024-11-30 12:36:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2024-11-30 12:36:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.google.com/> (referer: None)
>>> response.xpath('//script')
[<Selector query='//script' data='<script nonce="HGzmQO5tqFTVnT_NTw2JDQ...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script nonce="HGzmQO5tqFTVnT_NTw2JDQ...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script nonce="HGzmQO5tqFTVnT_NTw2JDQ...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script nonce="HGzmQO5tqFTVnT_NTw2JDQ...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script nonce="HGzmQO5tqFTVnT_NTw2JDQ...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script nonce="HGzmQO5tqFTVnT_NTw2JDQ...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script nonce="HGzmQO5tqFTVnT_NTw2JDQ...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script nonce="HGzmQO5tqFTVnT_NTw2JDQ...'>]
>>> fetch('https://scrapy.org/')
2024-11-30 12:36:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://scrapy.org/> (referer: None)
>>> response.xpath('//script')
[<Selector query='//script' data="<script>\n(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['...">, <Selector query='//script' data='<script type="text/javascript">\n!func...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script id="6senseWebTag" src="https:...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script src="//scrapinghub.refersion....'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script>try { _refersion(); } catch (...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script async src="https://www.google...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script>\n  window.dataLayer = window....'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script>\n!function(q,e,v,n,t,s){if(q....'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script>\n  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)\n ...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script type="text/javascript">\n_link...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script type="text/javascript">\n(func...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script src="/js/widynamic.js" defer>...'>, <Selector query='//script' data='<script type="text/javascript">\n\twind...'>]
>>> fetch('https://www.google.com/')
2024-11-30 12:37:00 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://consent.google.com/ml?continue=https://www.google.com/&gl=IT&m=0&pc=shp&uxe=none&cm=2&hl=it&src=1> from <GET https://www.google.com/>
2024-11-30 12:37:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://consent.google.com/ml?continue=https://www.google.com/&gl=IT&m=0&pc=shp&uxe=none&cm=2&hl=it&src=1> (referer: None)
>>> response.xpath('//script')
[]

I don't understand why I didn't have a script tag the second time I fetched Google. I don't have script tags for another website, not even at the first fetch. I cannot explain why it happens.
I'm using Scrapy 2.11.2.
Do you have any hints about this issue?
p.s. If I fetch the same page with curl I see the script tag.

Based on the url, the second time around Google wants you to consent to something, so it redirects you (302 statuscode). As a guess: clear cookies before the second fetch

Good catch. I overlooked that response status, and you're right. Moreover, I've also found that the returned HTML depends on the user agent. I discovered that I didn't have <script> tags without specifying the user agent.

As in the comments, the issue was on cookie management. Moreover, I discovered the problem was on the default user agent in another case. Specifying it would fix the issue.
